# Google Play Services How to fix?

Tags: oppo-coloros

I cant use Google apps because of the Google Play Services. in my notification Google App wont run without Google Play Services, Which are missing from your device. How do i fix this? i cant find my Google Play Services too.but i tried to download it but then browser said that Google Play Services is intalled in my device

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with the installation of google play services, it's actually with the updation of google play services .
To fix either go to googleplay store and update the services or click on the notif that says "this app won't run unless you update google play services".

hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Google Play Services isn't disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a corrupt Google play services app. You can download Tibu to force remove system apps and then reinstall it again to see if that works. Otherwise you probably need to factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try flashing [OpenGapps](https://opengapps.org/). It should fix the Google apps as a whole.